# Kivy, apk crash on phone

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I Use Kivy, python, and when I want to launch my app on my phone, my app crash immediately. In my file I use the camera, scan library pyzbar, cv2 to inverse level of gray, json and request to use API

This is the file, who crashed the application

```py
# Librairies Kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.bubble import BubbleButton
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture

# Librairies pour la fonction de scan / Librairies pour l'API (requests, json)
import cv2, requests, json
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import numpy as np

# Fichiers internes
from productpage import ProductPageScreen # Page du produit


# Ecran pour scanner les codes-barres
class BarcodeScannerScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BarcodeScannerScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bubble = BubbleButton(size_hint=(None, None), size=("200dp", "60dp")) # Bulle d'information

        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        # Ajouter la caméra
        self.camera = Camera(play=True, resolution=(240, 680), size_hint=(1, 0.8))
        self.camera.bind(on_texture=self.update_texture)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.camera)

        self.add_widget(self.layout)
    
    # Bouton retour de la page
    def back(self):
        from scan import ScanScreen
        screen_manager = self.manager
        scan_screen = ScanScreen(name='Scan')
        screen_manager.add_widget(scan_screen)
        screen_manager.current = 'Scan'
    
    # Fonction principale --> Scan des codes-barres
    def update_texture(self, *args):
        # Vérifier si la texture de la caméra est disponible
        if self.camera.texture:
            # Récupérer la texture de la caméra
            texture = self.camera.texture

            # Convertir la texture en une image OpenCV
            frame = texture.pixels
            img = np.frombuffer(frame, np.uint8).reshape(texture.height, texture.width, -1)

            # Miroir vertical
            img = cv2.flip(img, 0)

            # Convertir l'image en niveaux de gris
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            # Décoder les codes-barres dans l'image
            barcodes = decode(gray)

            # Afficher les résultats
            if barcodes:
                barcode_data = barcodes[0].data.decode("utf-8")
                #self.label.text = f"Code-barres détecté : {barcode_data}"

                api_url = "https://www.test.fr/api"
                api_key = "kra9d3rqmuk8nazedc1234khtadncwxf948s63cms83y5fxrhdz3"
                bare_code = barcode_data
                token = open('token.txt')
                
                request =  f"{api_url}?POC-api-key={api_key}&token={token.read()}&barcode={bare_code}" # Requête

                payload = {}
                response = requests.request("GET", request, data=payload)

                status_code = response.json().get("code")

                refe = response.json().get("refe")
                id = response.json().get("id")
                name = response.json().get("name")
                image = response.json().get("image")
                multiple = response.json().get("multiple")

                stock = response.json().get("stock")

                if:
                    self.manager.current = 'Product'
                    with open('product_infos.json', 'w') as f:
                        
                        json_data = {
                            "id": id,
                            "refe": refe,
                            "name": name,
                            "image": image,
                            "stock": stock,
                            "barcode": barcode_data,
                            "multiple": multiple
                        }

                        json.dump(json_data, f)
                        f.close()

# Application
class BarcodeScannerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Créer le ScreenManager
        sm = ScreenManager()

        # Ajouter les écrans
        from login import LoginScreen
        from scan import ScanScreen
        from selectquantity import QuantityScreen
        sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='Login'))
        sm.add_widget(ScanScreen(name='Scan'))
        sm.add_widget(BarcodeScannerScreen(name='Scanner'))
        sm.add_widget(ProductPageScreen(name='Product'))
        sm.add_widget(QuantityScreen(name='Quantity'))

        # Planifier la détection des codes-barres
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: sm.current_screen.update_texture(), 1.0)
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1) # Fond blanc (RGBA)

        return sm

# Appeler la class BarcodeScannerApp() si le fichier est lancé
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1) # Fond blanc (RGBA)
    BarcodeScannerApp().run() # Lancer la class
```

I have try to debug my APK with Android Studio and I have this error, but I haven't find solution I have this error

2023-07-07 11:14:13.864 8963-8968/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x40 in tid 8968 (Jit thread pool), pid 8963 (SDLActivity)

I know it say that : Application tries to access an invalid memory address

ANd I have also an error wit adb logcat

700 848 E InputDispatcher: channel '2e32efa fr.test.poc.poc/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

I haven't find solutions for this two errors

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).